# проблема с прогоном api тестов на jenkins

Tags: api, jenkins

1. Тесты пишутся с помощью Postman
2. для прогона на Jenkins используется newman 3.1.0
3. есть lxc-контейнер с установленным ПО, на котором jenkins прогоняет тест
4. при прогоне на jenkins  этот тест падает
5. поставила локально newman той же версии, что использует jenkins, тест прогоняется успешно на том же lxc-контейнере (т.е. тестовые данные одни и те же)

мое мнение, проблемы где-то в jenkins. возможно кто-либо сталкивался с аналогичным либо есть идеи, как исправить такое поведение. заранее спасибо